# How to sync photos from google photo to shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I have a lot of pictures on google photo and I want to sync them to shotwell for more convenient. Is there anyway to do that? And sorry for the bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. Both are different, independent systems with no integration between them thus far.

Answer (score 0):

There's not direct integration (via "Import from Application") between Google Photos and Shotwell.

However, given an extra step, you can take advantage of Google Photos Sync ([gphotos-sync](https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync)) to download your Google Photos to your computer. gphotos-sync also organizes the media in the local file system using album information. Additional Google Photos 'Creations' such as animations, panoramas, movies, effects and collages are also backed up.

Then from Shotwell you can use the "Import from Folder" functionality.

Yet please note, it is a one-directional approach, no two-way-sync is possible.